# Ошибка при установке bitcoinlib

Tags: python, python-3.x

помогите разобраться чего не хватает системе для установки

```
pip install bitcoinlib
```

Выходят много ошибок
скрин предоставляю
[image: вот]

Текст ошибки

```
D:\Soft\777\newscripts>pip install bitcoinlib
Collecting bitcoinlib
  Using cached bitcoinlib-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (318 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: ecdsa==0.16 in c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from bitcoinlib) (0.16.0)
Collecting scrypt==0.8.17
  Using cached scrypt-0.8.17.tar.gz (56 kB)
Collecting pyaes==1.6.1
  Using cached pyaes-1.6.1.tar.gz (28 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.19.5
  Using cached numpy-1.19.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (13.3 MB)
Collecting requests==2.25.1
  Using cached requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy==1.3.22 in c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from bitcoinlib) (1.3.22)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from ecdsa==0.16->bitcoinlib) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests==2.25.1->bitcoinlib) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests==2.25.1->bitcoinlib) (1.25.10)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests==2.25.1->bitcoinlib) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests==2.25.1->bitcoinlib) (3.0.4)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaes, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for scrypt, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: scrypt, requests, pyaes, numpy, bitcoinlib
  Attempting uninstall: scrypt
    Found existing installation: scrypt 0.8.18
    Uninstalling scrypt-0.8.18:
      Successfully uninstalled scrypt-0.8.18
    Running setup.py install for scrypt ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4j7vy0it\\scrypt_9389e501220d4b91a75db180dc0b3c05\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4j7vy0it\\scrypt_9389e501220d4b91a75db180dc0b3c05\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8ctppy_y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python\python39\Include\scrypt'
         cwd: C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4j7vy0it\scrypt_9389e501220d4b91a75db180dc0b3c05\
    Complete output (50 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt
    copying scrypt\scrypt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt
    copying scrypt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt_c_module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt_py2x.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt_py3x.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\ciphertexts.csv -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    copying scrypt\tests\hashvectors.csv -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\scrypt\tests
    running build_ext
    building '_scrypt' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib\crypto
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib\scryptenc
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib\util
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva\alg
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva\crypto
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva\util
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-windows-stubs
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python\python39\include -Ic:\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt.obj
    crypto_scrypt.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python\python39\include -Ic:\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix.obj
    crypto_scrypt_smix.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python\python39\include -Ic:\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix_sse2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix_sse2.obj
    crypto_scrypt_smix_sse2.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python\python39\include -Ic:\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc.obj
    scryptenc.c
    scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc.c(125): warning C4244: =: ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ "size_t" ў "double", ў®§¬®¦­  Ї®вҐап ¤ ­­ле
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python\python39\include -Ic:\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc_cpuperf.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc_cpuperf.obj
    scryptenc_cpuperf.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python\python39\include -Ic:\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util/memlimit.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/util/memlimit.obj
    memlimit.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python\python39\include -Ic:\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg/sha256.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg/sha256.obj
    sha256.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -Ic:\python\python39\include -Ic:\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.obj
    crypto_aes.c
    scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.c(6): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of scrypt
  Moving to c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\_scrypt.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
   from C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-c2r_awwd\_scrypt.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
  Moving to c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrypt-0.8.18.dist-info\
   from C:\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~crypt-0.8.18.dist-info
  Moving to c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrypt\
   from C:\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~crypt
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4j7vy0it\\scrypt_9389e501220d4b91a75db180dc0b3c05\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4j7vy0it\\scrypt_9389e501220d4b91a75db180dc0b3c05\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8ctppy_y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python\python39\Include\scrypt' Check the logs for full command output.

D:\Soft\777\newscripts>
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас предоставлю

Comment: 'openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory' похоже, в python 3.9 под win10 [не хватает библиотеки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383942/how-to-use-openssl-with-visual-studio)... или попробуйте откатиться до python 3.8

Comment: попробую и напишу о результате

Answer (score 0):

нужно откатиться до python 3.8

Comment: Нужно ставить 64-битную версию питона 3.9

Comment: ставил 64 как раз таки, но там эта библиотека не хочет устанавливаться.

Comment: Это странно, scrypt вполне существует для 64-битного питона 3.9 и должен был установиться без проблем

Comment: А, вот оно в чём причина `package 'wheel' is not installed.` — вам нужно сперва установить пакет `wheel` и уже потом всё остальное нормально установится

Comment: спасибо, проверю потом отпишу